# Not able to get the rest of data grid view column names after a particular column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to get all the names of the columns inside of the rows in a datagridview. However, it stops showing after a particular column is reached (the email column). Not sure why, as I have it set to loop through the rows.

Anyways, here is my code:

```
// not returning name after email..
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewMembers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridViewMembers.Columns[i].Name);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the program running:

[image]
As you hopefully can see, it only displays the column name up until email, leaving out birthday, anniversary, and married. These 3 fields are in my database table, sorry, I had to black out the information.

I can provide more information if need be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your loop is running on **rows**, not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is running on rows, not columns. Change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewMembers.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridViewMembers.Columns[i].Name);
}
```